# How many ways are there to write $10$ as an ordered sum of positive integers less than or equal to $3$

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to write $10$ as an ordered sum of positive integers less than or equal to $3$.
For example:- $10 = 3 + 3 + 2 + 2, \; 10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 2$

I tried evalutaing each individual cases and found $269$ permutations, answer isn't correct. Doing most of the question in a brute force way is a bad idea.
Any other way to do it?

This is my evaluation

[image]

$OK!$, found the mistake. $4^{th}$ case isn't evaluated correctly, it's $15$ not $10$. I should be ashamed of myself for doing such silly mistakes.

Comment: Have you considered doing it recursively?  Like a recurrence relation?

Comment: I don't know much about recurrence relation, I haven't studied it.

Comment: Where did this problem come from if I might ask?

Comment: I was scrolling Po Shen Loh's website and found the Combinatorics section.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671168/number-of-ways-to-distribute-n-identical-balls-into-k-identical-boxes-such-t/4671229#4671229) answer your question ?

Comment: I am not able to understand the solution provided in that post. But thanks for telling me about the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by brute force, but 10 is at least reasonably small, so it might be worthwhile.  Start by defining a function.  Let's call it $f[n]$ and define it as the number of ways $n$ can be written as an ordered sum of positive integers less than or equal to 3.  There are 3 possibilities: the first value of the sum is a 3, in which case the rest of the summation adds up to 7 and similarly for 2 and 1.  This leads to a recurrence relation $$f[n]=f[n-3]+f[n-2]+f[n-1]$$

Now all we need are some starting values.  It might be easier to define $f[0]=1$.  1 gets 1 representation as just 1 and 2 can be written as 1+1 or 2, so $f[1]=1$ and $f[2]=2$.  The problem asks for $f[10]$.  Now just simply solve for the next value until you get to $10$.  $f[3]=f[2]+f[1]+f[0]=2+1+1=4$, then solve for $f[4]$ and on down the list.

Comment: I added my solution

Comment: The answer is coming out to be $274$ and yes it is showing correct as well. Thanks! I think I have to learn a new tool "Recurrence Relation".

Comment: Mine is $269, 5$ less than the correct one, I was so close. May be I am missing one or some case or may be my calculation of permutations isn't correct.

Comment: I corrected my answer, it was a calculation mistake.