# What are the number of possible combinations for rolling N indistinguishable dice obtaining a total punctuation p?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to compute the number of possible combinations when rolling N indistinguishable dice to obtain a total punctuation p. I got the formula for distinguishable dice, but I cannot figure out how to solve it without counting permutations.

Comment: What do you mean by "total punctuation $p$" ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Total number of dots (points), I suppose.

Comment: There are a lot of answers for this question here on this site, just use the search function on this site, or better yet, use google with “site:math.stackexchange.com” added to your query.

Comment: To be clear, the value you ask for may be a worthy exercise for its own right... will not really be useful for any real world calculations.  It will not be useful for any calculations involving probability of rolling dice, regardless of whether or not the dice are distinguishable... since any real world example throwing dice will involve physical objects who occupy different positions in space-time and as such are treated as distinct for the purposes of modeling the probability distributions at play.

Comment: You could look at the coefficient of $x^Ny^p$ of the expansion of $(1+xy+(xy)^2+(xy)^3+\dots)(1+xy^2+(xy^2)^2+(xy^2)^3+\dots)\dots(1+xy^6+(xy^6)^2+(xy^6)^3+\dots)$ if you were content with computer help.

Comment: A smarter approach might be to build up a recursive function... maybe breaking into cases based on the largest available value and how many of said largest available value had occurred.  Letting $F(n,p,\ell)$ be our function, $n$ dice being thrown totaling $p$ with $\ell$ the largest seen value, we would have $F(n,p,\ell) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n F(n-i,p-\ell i,\ell-1)$ and we would have clear boundary conditions that $F(n,n,1)=1$ and $F(n,p,1)=0$ for $n\neq p$.

Comment: Think of each dice as a box, and each dot on the die face as a ball. Each box has between $1$ and $6$ balls. If you remove one ball from each box, then there are a total of $p-N$ identical balls in these $N$ identical boxes, where each box as at most $5$ balls. Therefore, your question is answered by this earlier question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671168/number-of-ways-to-distribute-n-identical-balls-into-k-identical-boxes-such-t